# parse a byte string from a binary input using php

Tags: php

I'm very new to PHP.
I need some help parsing a byte string from a binary input.

```
For example : input= 020104020107020108020103.
```

From the example, I need to extract any byte after `0201`.

```
 I mean --> 04, 07, 08, 03.
```

Save every value to a variable and identify the last one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are certain that every byte will be prefixed with `0201` and that every byte will use up 2 characters, then you can use the following code:

```
<?php

$input = "020104020107020108020103";
$bytes = [];

for ($i = 4; $i < strlen($input); ++$i) {
    $byte = substr($input, $i, 2);

    array_push($bytes, $byte);

    // 1 byte + 4 byte (0201 offset)
    $i += 5;
}

print_r($bytes);
```